# Why do native speakers read "he was" like "use"?

Tags: pronunciation

> The chromite petered out in a month and a half, and **he was** lucky to
>   break even.

[sound track](https://soundcloud.com/xi-zhang-819295156/all-day-september-kuykendall)

That makes me very hard to hear clear.

Comment: It doesn't sound like **use** to this US English speaker, but I agree that he does mush together "he was" into something that is not very clear.  [Here is an example of someone saying "he was" and "use" in the same sentence, so you can hear the difference.](https://www.naturalreaders.com/online?s=V270iefg6pxoo40okwoksssccgk.pdf&t=NaturalReader%20Document)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not assume that because you find an example of a native English speaker using bad pronunciation, or even bad grammar, that all native speakers do the same.  In this case the speaker is saying 'he was' but:

1/ he is running the two words very closely together, and

2/ he is pronouncing 'was' as if it was pronounced closer to 'wiz', so it comes out sounding like:

'e'wiz'

Both of these are common habits among some native English speakers. If you listen to people speaking in your own language, I am sure that you will find a similar level of variation in how different people say the same sound.